# Automatically cast values to required type - C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, dll, casting, abstraction

I use a dll to controll some hardware, and there are two versions of the hardware (and the dll). Some functions have changed, but most of the functions provided by the dll have stayed the same - except that in the newer version, parameters are always provided as `Int32`, `UInt32`, and in the old version it was `short` and `ushort`.

I created a wrapper class for both versions of the dll that inherits from the dll and provides additional features and masks the functions that acutally did change. By just changing one `using`, the programm can than be compiled for the old or the new version, and I don't have to write and maintain a big chunk of code twice.

But now I am starting to redefine every function of the dll because of the changed signature like this, which isn't exactly fun:

```
class ABCWrapper : ABC_V1
{
...
    public new static void jump_abs(Int32 x_abs, Int32 y_abs)
   {
        ABC_V1.jump_abs((short)x_abs, (short)y_abs);
    }
...
}
```

Is there any way to do this automatically, like defining sth. as "Is function inherited from `ABC_V1`? Yes -> Try explicit cast of parameter" or something?

Comment: Does your wrapper contain only static methods? If it does - inheritance is probably not required here. You call base static class methods directly. This can help to eliminate 'new' keyword. As for automatic cast - I believe there is no such feature in C#, but some of things you can try is code generation, or using 'short' in wrapper instead of 'int' - you cast to short anyway.